# Use DBCC CHECKDB in java

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have to use DBCC CHECKDB command in JDBC. I tried it with `PreparedStatement` and it shows an error. The error shows that no resultset is returned. How can I do it?

Comment: Please update your error msg.

Comment: Please provide more detail like the statement you ran and the exact error message you got.

Answer (score 0):

Without the actual code or error message, this answer is mostly guessing:

You probably use `preparedStatement.executeQuery()` while you should use `preparedStatement.execute()`. The former requires a result while the later works with or without a result set returned from the statement.